# Is there a standard way to refer to an example language?

Tags: terminology, examples

What is the John Doe or John Smith of language names for when a linguist is making an example?

We’ve all seen

> Suppose that in **language**  . . .

and

> Imagine **a language** . . .

and in another post, I saw

> [a **language Gwambomambo** which lacks the word . . .](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/26312)

Is there a more common way to refer to a dummy language without using a plausible-sounding name as the last example does?

Comment: I think what I see is "imagine a language L"... or "a language L1"...

Comment: Well, if you go that far, you're already talking about math and not linguistics. There's no reason to invent or imagine a language with certain properties if you can't find one that actually does; if you did imagine it and needed to name it, a good name might be one that preserves the properties you imagined it with, like "English without _be_" or "SOV French".

Comment: I think it's a good question. L1 and L2 sound fine to me.

Comment: @jlawler I remembered one actual source, Chomsky’s *Syntactic Structures*: “[…] a general theory of linguistic structure in which such notions as “phoneme in L”, “phrase in L” […] are defined for an arbitrary language L”.

Comment: Like I said, math. The actual linguistic phenomena are waved away as already defined, and then the serious work of abstraction begins.